# array_push() method expects parameter 1 to be array but null is given

Tags: php

What exactly wrong in this code?

```
      $user_friends_bday_set = array();
      function isFullDate($target, $array) {
        array_filter($array, function($friendo){
          if(isset($friendo['bdate']) && strlen($friendo['bdate'])>5 ){
            array_push($target, $friendo);
            return $target;
          }//IF
        });//ARRAYFILTER
      };

  $user_friends_bday_set = isFullDate($user_friends_bday_set, $user_friends_arr);
```

Why $user_friends_bday_set is null?

Comment: Seems `$target` is null

Comment: `$target` is unknown in your `function($friendo) ...`

Comment: My answer is exactly Why this array is null...

Comment: how to make it declared?

Comment: $user_friends_bday_set = array(); is definition of it.

Comment: `$target` is unknow is what we're saying, not `$user_friends_bday_set`

Comment: where should I define it?

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `array_filter()` in this code?  You seem to use it to create another array.

Comment: Edit your question and add some example input.  As Nigel suggests array_filter doesn't feel like the right fit here.

Answer (score 3):

`$target` is unknown to your `function($friendo) ...`. Change your code to

```
$user_friends_bday_set = array();
function isFullDate($target, $array) {
  array_filter($array, function($friendo) use (&$target) {
    if(isset($friendo['bdate']) && strlen($friendo['bdate'])>5 ){
      array_push($target, $friendo);
        return $target;
    }//IF
  });//ARRAYFILTER
};
```

`use(&$target)` has been added so your closure knows about `$target`.

Read more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: `use(&$target)` to make it a reference as OP changes its value.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks